# how to write xml file in docs directory of iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, passwords

I need to store my username and password in to a xml file in this format

```
   <user>abcde</user>
   <pass>123355</pass>
```

How I can write this file so that i can read it easily?

Comment: If you are storing 'secrets' like passwords, you should probably look into using the keychain.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Mike .. you should use keychain to store passwords..google it ..there are tutorials available online.

As for the xml storing.
Here is the code

```
     NSData *serializedData;
        NSString *error;
        serializedData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:YourArray(You can use dictionaries.strings..and others too)
        format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
        if (serializedData) {
        // Serialization was successful, write the data to the file system // Get an array of paths.

       NSArray *documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@”%@/serialized.xml”,
         [documentDirectoryPath objectAtIndex:0]];
        ￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼[serializedData writeToFile:docDir atomically:YES];
 }
        else {
        // An error has occurred, log it
        NSLog(@”Error: %@”,error); }
        }
```